# jquery textfield: show end of text when not in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I see that whenever there is more text than the size of the text field, start of the text gets shown when not on focus. In the picture below, i want to show the end of the text like 1, but when text field is not in focus automatically start of the text is shown. I tried right align (bootstrap text-right) as shown in 3 but that didn't help

[image: Textfields]

Code chunk related to this:

```
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-3">Work Space:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="workspace" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <button type="button" id="load_files" class="btn btn-info">Load Files</button>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Edit:

Just tried this in Mozilla firefox, it works just as i want it to, but doesn't work in chrome

Comment: Hmm... Have you tried `contenteitable`?

Comment: Can you include your code?

Comment: @Igor - Added relevant code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `direction` CSS property to match the direction of the text you want. `rtl` or `ltr`.

```
input {
  direction: rtl;
}
input:focus,
input:active {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

Here's a fiddle demo for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/on91y1hr/